# Click on a link and save ID to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm working in HTML and JavaScript. I have two HTML pages ("people.html" and "profile.html") and one JavaScript file ("people.js") with an object in it with a list of names. Each name has its own ID, like so:

```
var persons = [
{
    "firstName": "Dwight",
    "surName": "Stender",
    "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/99.jpg",
"id": "1"
},
{
    "firstName": "Cole",
    "surName": "Turek",
    "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/66.jpg",
"id": "2"
}]
```

On the first page I show all people and when I click on a "Details" button it goes to the second page (this was done with handlebars.js) like this:

```
<!-- Use handlebars and javascript to show all people in the object with one script -->
      <script id="users-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">


        {% raw %}

        {{#each this}}
          <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="user">
                <img src="{{picture}}" class="profpic"/>
                <h4>{{firstName}} {{surName}}</h4>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default profileLink" id="{{id}}" href="profile.html?id={{id}}" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}

        {% endraw %}


      </script>
```

Now my question is, is there a way to use JavaScript to save the ID (of the link I just clicked) to a different variable when I click on it. For example, if I click on the profile with ID 2, can I save that number 2 to a variable that updates itself when I go back and click on another ID?

The purpose of that second variable is so I can show only the information of that specific person on the second page. So I would call that variable on the second page and compare it to the object ID's, and where the ID's match I would print that name to the screen.

EDIT: I've found out why your suggestions weren't working (I think). I believe I left out a piece of important information: the link with the ID I want to store is already inside a script. So does localstorage work when you try to reach something inside another script?

Comment: When you want that ID in variable, after redirection?

Comment: I'd reconsider what your'e doing entirely because it seems like you're heading down a road of bad practices that might just potentially cause more problems in the future. Without knowing why you'd want to do this though I would suggest either using Cookies or [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store that ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using jquery use below code to get the id

Please make sure all links have same class name.

```
<!--a class="classOfLink id="1" "href="url">Example headline</a--> 
var clickedId;
  $(".classOfLink").click(function()
     {
        clickedId = $(this).attr("id");// this will give object of current clicked link

     });
```

You can later pass this id as a parameter in url or update any variable in local storage as per your need like below.

```
localStorage.setItem('id', clickedId);
```

**Please mark it as an answer if its matching your requirement.**

Comment: I feel like this is what I was looking for, but when I tested it (logged it to the console) it said "undefined"?

Comment: While implementing this please make sure you implement below points. 1) Class name of all links should be same. 2) All links should have id.  Can you let me know exactly which statement is giving undefined.   Please attach your code after my changes

Comment: I have put my code and explanation in this google doc because it was too long to post in comments

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1n16j-t2yp1a9P0qNvBOqhxroIqny7YQlHZALtHPX244/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I cannot check your link in my current network , But i will get back to you ASAP

Answer (score 3):

You could use local storage for persistence across page loads.

```
// IF button click 1
localStorage.setItem('id', 1);
// IF button click 2
localStorage.setItem('id', 2);

console.log(localStorage.getItem('id'))
```

Comment: Does localstorage work when the item I want is already inside a script?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know exactly what you mean by inside a script.  `localStorage` is on the window object and will always be available for you.